# Django database relationships - many-to-many, many-to-one

Tags: python, django

I can't seem to conceptually differentiate between many-to-one and many-to-many relationships in django. I understand how they work in SQL and databases and understand the concept of foreign key, etc by heart BUT for example I don't understand the following:

Both ends of a many-to-many relationship get automatic API access to the other end. The API works just as a “backward” one-to-many relationship. However, I still cant see it conceptually.

MANY-TO-ONE example:

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = (’headline’,)
```

I could do this:

```
>>> r = Reporter(first_name=’John’, last_name=’Smith’, email=’john@example.com’)
>>> r.save()
>>> a = Article(id=None, headline="This is a test", pub_date=datetime(2005, 7, 27), reporter=r)
>>> a.save()
>>> a.reporter
<Reporter: John Smith>
```

So, I could get to the Reporters class from Articles class via foreign key.

MANY-TO-MANY example:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = (’title’,)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = (’headline’,)
```

My question is - I could get to Publication class via ManyToManyField on Article class just like I did above in Many-to-One class. So how does M2M differs from M2one? What are the other things I could do with m2m. (I could of course do reverse on both but I am trying to ignore reverse relationships for both for the time being so as not to confuse myself further.)
So to better phrase my question what else does one normally do with m2m which one normally doesnt with m2one?

Disclaimer - new to programming but read the whole 100 page section on models of django official docs so please don't refer me to them if you can. I am already learning from them.

Also I can understand better in code so please include some code examples if you can.

Answer (score 1):

> **One** reporter could have **many** articles, but an article just has **one**
>   reporter.

```
# This will get the reporter of an article
article.reporter
# This will get all the articles of a reporter
reporter.article_set.all()
# You cannot add another reporter to an article
article.reporter.add(r) # This will raise an Error!
```

On the other hand,

> **One** article could have **many** publications, and a publication could be related to **many** articles.

```
# This will get all the publications of an article
article.publications.all()
# This will get all the related articles of a publication
publication.article_set.all()
# You CAN add another publication to an article
article.publications.add(p) # No Error here
```

Comment: i understand the basics. I get that. But what more could I do with django ManyToManyField that I cant with ManyToOne Foreign Key.

Comment: @julio.algeria Appreciate it. So "article.reporter.add(r) # This will raise an Error!". Using a M2M field one can make changes/write in the table of the related class. but foreign key on M2one can only "read". Sorry if I am being overly dense today.